# How do I configure Teams notifications specifically for GitLab merge request creation?

Tags: gitlab, jira, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I've been exploring the possibilities of having receiving a notification on my Teams channel whenever a new merge request on GitLab is created.

So far I've looked into `Project -> Settings -> Webhooks -> Merge requests events`, but such a webhook sends a notification when a merge request is created, updated, closed and reopened. Receiving notifications on all of these events creates a lot of noise in the Teams channel. Therefore, I would like to only receive a notification when a merge request is **created**.

I'm also using Jira, with it being connected to GitLab. This means that most Jira issue have entries in the **Merge Request** tab. Maybe Jira has more refined webhook settings that can trigger only when a merge request in GitLab is created?

My plans was to find some sort of webhook that only triggers when reating a merge request, or to have some sort of *filter* in the Teams channel to block out webhook messages that i.e. contains the word "updated", but I haven't been able to find any of these features.

Comment: To receive a notification on your Teams channel whenever a new merge request is created in GitLab, you can use Incoming Webhooks in Microsoft Teams. Incoming Webhooks allow you to post messages from your apps to Teams channels.
 you can refer to the Incoming Webhook notification sample documentation.-https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/ga/incoming-webhook-notification#getting-started-with-incoming-webhook-notification-sample